# manipulate iframe content in phonegap app with javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, iframe

I would like to access a form which is in an iframe. The page inside this iframe is from an other domain. However, I am inside phonegap/native (iOS). In a browser I noticed I can only access and manipulate the iframe content if the page is from the same origin. Because in phonegap, things like XSS do not exist, I would expect that I can access an iframe from an other domain. 
Anyway, just in case this is possible, here is my code:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://login.site.com" width="500" height="500"></iframe>

....

var $ifc = $('#iframe').contents() ;
$ifc.find("input[name=username]").val("Bob");
$ifc.find("input[name=password]").val("secret");
$ifc.find("input[type=submit]").click() ;
```

This also shows what I want to achieve; automatically fill in the login form and submit

Any suggestions ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Iframes [don't work very well](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage) in Phonegap.

However, accessing the iframe through javascript should be possible.

```
var iframeDoc = document.getElementById("iframe").document;
```

Comment: if I do that, it returns "undefined"

Comment: Hmm... would it be possible to recreate the form that you want to post within your own script?